# Xcode - Semantic issue only on 64-bit

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, 64-bit, ios-simulator

So I am working on an app with a team where I have to install pods.
One of those pods is causing me trouble when building. When I run my app on the iPhone Retina (3.5 inch) and the iPhone retina (4 inch) simulators, it works, no errors. When I try to build the app for iPhone Retina (4 inch 64-bit), it will give me errors.

Same thing with the iPad simulators. It seems as if its only giving me errors when I build it for 64-bit simulators.

The errors I am getting are both:
Semantic Issue 
Type of property 'variable' ('int') does not match type of instance variable 'variable' ('long').

I believe the error might lie in the build settings.

Comment: on 32 bit systems, ints and longs are both 4 bytes, on 64 bit systems, int is 4 bytes and long is (mostly) 8 bytes, so you could be getting warnings due to that fact, if you explicitly cast it you should get the warnings away

Comment: bam, good answer Fonix

Comment: @Fonix Its not a warning. Its an error. And its not my code. Its third party code.

Comment: ah that is quite odd, and unfortunate... a problem ive had that was 64bit specific was that tableview delegates that we expecting CGFloats as a return type were having `-(float)` in the methods return type, and changing that to CGFloat fixed the problem. So maybe you can do a find replace with your ints/longs and make them like NSIntegers or something, otherwise im not too sure unfortunately